# Number of ways a penalty kick shootout can be decided in the first round

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This is question from *Discrete Maths* by Kenneth H. Rosen.

> This procedure is used to break ties in games in the championship round of the World Cup soccer tournament. Each team selects five players in a prescribed order. Each of these players takes a penalty kick, with a player from the first team followed by a player from the second team and so on, following the order of players specified.
>
> If the score is still tied at the end of the 10 penalty kicks, this procedure is repeated. If the score is still tied after 20 penalty kicks, a sudden-death shootout occurs, with the first team scoring an unanswered goal victorious.
>
> - a) How many different scoring scenarios are possible if the game is settled in the first round of 10 penalty kicks, where the round ends once it is impossible for a team to equal the number of goals scored by the other team?
> - b) How many different scoring scenarios for the first and second groups of penalty kicks are possible if the game is settled in the second round of 10 penalty kicks?
> - c) How many scoring scenarios are possible for the full set of penalty kicks if the game is settled with no more than 10 total additional kicks after the two rounds of five kicks for each team?

I tried to solve part(a). There are three possible outcome of each kick. Either team 1 or team 2 wins or ties. So there are $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$ possible outcome of 5 penalty kicks. Now we should subtract those in which we don't need to play till 5 penalty kicks. Am I thinking in right way? There is no solution given in book. So I can't verify.

Same approach for part(b). And part(c), I am not even able to understand the question. Please help .

Comment: I do not understand your claim that there are three possible outcomes for each kick.  If team A shoots before team B, then there are four possible outcomes:  $(s, s), (s, f), (f, s), (f, f)$, where $s$ indicates a successful shot and $f$ indicates a failed shot.

Comment: If team A successful in kick one and team B fails in it's kick one then team A wins kick one. Similarly if team A fails and team B succeeds in their respective first kick then team B wins. If both team fails to score in their first kick, so it is tie. So there are 3 possibility of outcome of each kick.

Comment: The order in which the shots are taken matters.  For instance, if A shoots first and has a 3 - 0 lead after 5 penalty kicks, it is still possible for B to be tied with A after ten penalty kicks.  However, if A retains that 3 - 0 lead after six penalty kicks, A wins the game, so no further shots are taken.

Comment: The question did not define what is a "scoring scenario", but I would agree with @N.F.Taussig that two scenarios are different (distinctly counted) if _any_ individual kick is different (in or out).  So $(s,s)$ and $(f,f)$ would IMHO count as different.

Comment: Yes, this questions lacks clarity. Should we solve it with tree diagram with each penalty kick branching out for 3 outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked about 2 years ago, but it is never too late if the outcome is good!

## Compute the total amount of 10-penalty shoot-out combinations

The way I solved this problem was to compute all possible combinations for the first-to-shoot team (team A) in order to win, lose or draw with respect to the other team (team B) in the 10-penalty shoot-out. The green ticks and the red crosses indicate whether a penalty is scored or not, respectively. I used tuples for counting the number of goals and misses for each scenario.

Notice that some of the shoots are shaded, indicating the relevant shots to permute for getting new combinations without duplicates. The $C(n, r)$ operation stands for a $r$-combination with $n$ elements, where
$$
C(n, r) = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} = \binom{n}{r}.
$$

### Team A wins

#### Team B does not score goals

[image: Team A wins with 0 goals for team B]

#### Team B scores 1 goal

[image: Team A wins with 1 goal for team B]

#### Team B scores 2 goals

[image: Team A wins with 2 goals for team B]

#### Team B scores 3 goals

[image: Team A wins with 3 goals for team B]

#### Team B scores 4 goals

[image: Team A wins with 4 goals for team B]

If we add the total amount of combinations for each scenario, team A has $19 + 79 + 87 + 24 + 1 = 210$ ways of winning.

### Team B wins

#### Team A does not score goals

[image: Team B wins with 0 goals for team A]

#### Team A scores 1 goal

[image: Team B wins with 1 goal for team A]

#### Team A scores 2 goals

[image: Team B wins with 2 goals for team A]

#### Team A scores 3 goals

[image: Team B wins with 3 goals for team A]

#### Team A scores 4 goals

[image: Team B wins with 4 goals for team A]

If we add the total amount of combinations for each scenario, team B has $15 + 59 + 87 + 44 + 5 = 210$ ways of winning.

### Draw

For this case, both teams must score the same amount of penalties at the end of the shoot-out. Therefore, the number of possible combinations will be
$$
\sum_{r=0}^5C(5, r)^2 = 1^2 + 5^2 + 10^2 + 10^2 + 5^2 + 1^2 = 252.\tag{1}\label{eq:draw}
$$

## Solution

1. As we see, there are $210 + 210 = 420$ ways of settling the match in the first 10-penalty shoot-out.
2. Following the product rule and \eqref{eq:draw}, we need to multiply the number of ways to tie by the number of ways of winning or losing. Thus, there are $252 \cdot 420 = 105840$ ways of settling the match in the second 10-penalty shoot-out.
3. We have to add both previous answers including the rest of the combinations given by the sudden death. In order to continue in a sudden death, both teams must score or miss. The sudden death ends when team A scores and team B misses or viceversa. For a $n$ pair of penalty shots, this situation can be visualized as filling a bitstring with $n-1$ score-score and/or miss-miss results and a last one with a score-miss or miss-score result. This gives us $2^{n-1} \cdot 2 = 2^n$ possible combinations. Since $n$ must be less than $6$, a sudden death with $n<6$ pairs of penalty shots can be settled in
   $$
   \sum_{n=1}^52^n = 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 = 62\text{ ways}.
   $$
   Following the product rule, we will have $252 \cdot 252 \cdot 62 = 3937248$ ways of ending a sudden death with $n<6$ pairs of penalty shots. Therefore, the final answer is $420 + 105840 + 3937248 = 4043508$.

**Edited**:

2 figure have some errors, i.e. "Team A does not score goals" and "Team A scores 2 goals".

"Team A does not score goals" should be
[image: Team A does not score goals]

"Team A scores 2 goals" should be
[image: Team A scores 2 goals]

So team B has $12 + 59 + 90 + 44 + 5 = 210$ ways of winning.

You can compare them with the original ones. The tex codes to generate these 2 figures is shown in [this overleaf edit link](https://www.overleaf.com/3825868321jtxqnptbmkgm#1f9545). If you find some problems more with the above, you can use this template.

Here I show the small problems of the original ones.

1. The conversion from A(0,4),B(2,1) to A(0,4),B(2,2) should be similar to the conversion from A(1,3),B(3,0) to A(1,3),B(3,1). So we should fix the last tick of A in A(0,4),B(2,2).
2. The conversion from A(0,3),B(3,0) to A(1,3),B(3,0) where in the latter case when the last tick is put at the last it will be duplicate with the former case **isn't similar to**
   the conversion from A(1,3),B(3,0) to A(2,2),B(4,0) where in the latter case when one of the two ticks is put at the last it won't be duplicate with the former case since the last one goal of A in A(1,3),B(3,0) is **lost (i.e. cross symbol)**

We can also use the python code of the zg c's answer to check.

Answer (score -1):

Recently, I was also reading the above textbook and stuck at this problem when the author says in his 8-edition solution book where he doesn't recommend the exhaustion method by hand but recommends using **computer simulation**. So I offered **one sample python code for part a)** in the following:

> There are $2^{10} = 1024$
> possible scenarios without this rule (and without worrying yet about whether the score is tied at the end of
> this round), but it **seems rather tedious and dangerous** (in the sense of your being likely to make a mistake
> and leave something out) to try to analyze the more complicated situation by **writing out all the possibilities**
> by hand. (This is not impossible, though, and the author has obtained the correct answer in this way.) Rather
> than do this, one can **write a computer program to simulate the situation** and do the counting. The result is
> that there are 672 possible scoring scenarios for a round of penalty kicks, including the possibility that the
> score is still tied at the end of that round.

Then after hinted by the answer of Sebastián V. Romero, I wrote one python code to solve the part a). The basic ideas are similar to Sebastián V. Romero.

Here is the code although it may not one optimal code since when I wrote this post I was learning Discrete Maths as the preparation for self-learning the algorithm. Anyone with one better code solution can help improving this answer. Thanks beforehand.

```
"""
here I let shot_list[9] to be the first one by A and shot_list[8] being first by B.
The reasons are shown in the following context of ""i//(2**left_rounds)" conveniently". 
"""
shot_list=[0]*10
round_combination_duplicate_list=[False]*(2**10)
possibilities=0
"""
whether to include Draw/Tied situations when counting.
"""
INCLUDE_TIE=False
A_zero_win_B_finally_win=0

def Round_To_BitLocation(bit):
    return 9-bit
def BitLocation_To_Round(bit):
    return 9-bit
A_win=0
B_win=0
A_two_win_B_finally_win=0

"""
Here I traverse all possibilities with some skipped which may be not optimal.
Look forward for the improvement. Thanks beforehand.
"""
for i in range(0,2**10):
    """
    to skip duplicate counting like "101010xxxx", i.e. A(3,0) with B(3,0) in "Team B does not score goals"
    when "Team A wins"
    """
    if round_combination_duplicate_list[i]==True:
        continue
    A_score=0
    B_score=0
    A_round=5
    B_round=5
    for j in range(0,10):
        shot_list[j]=(i%2**(j+1))//2**(j)
        # print(i,shot_list)
    for j in range(0,10):
        if j%2==0:
            """
            here we assign from the MSB to use "i//(2**left_rounds)" conveniently 
            """
            A_score+=shot_list[Round_To_BitLocation(j)]
            A_round-=1
        else:
            B_score+=shot_list[Round_To_BitLocation(j)]
            B_round-=1
        """
        1. quote from the book solution:
            > the penalty kick round (or “group”) is over once one team has clinched a victory.
            i.e. one team A must win even if the other team B won the rest un-kicked round goals 
            while A lost all the rest un-kicked.
        2. This implies that they can't have same ticks (scores) even after filling the left un-kicked goals of one side with ticks
            So to calculate "draw" condition, we only need to care about:
            > both teams must score the same amount of penalties at the end of the shoot-out.
        """
        if (A_score>B_round+B_score) or (B_score>A_round+A_score):
            break
    left_rounds=A_round+B_round
    if left_rounds>0:
        """
        check the program correctness at one specific case.
        """
        if i//(2**4)==0b101010:
            print(bin(i),left_rounds,2**left_rounds,i//(2**left_rounds),i//(2**left_rounds)+2**left_rounds)
        start=i//(2**left_rounds)*(2**left_rounds)
        for tmp in range(start,start+2**left_rounds):
            round_combination_duplicate_list[tmp]=True
    if (A_score!=B_score) or INCLUDE_TIE:
        possibilities+=1
        # """
        # check "Team B wins" with "Team A does not score goals"
        # """
        # if (i&(0b101010<<4)==0) and (A_score==0):
        #     A_zero_win_B_finally_win+=1
        #     # https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-f-strings/ https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/
        #     print(f"{i:#010b}",left_rounds,2**left_rounds,i//(2**left_rounds),i//(2**left_rounds)+2**left_rounds)
        #     for j in range(0,10):
        #         if i&(1<<Round_To_BitLocation(j))!=0:
        #             if j%2==0:
        #                 print(f"A win at {j+1} round")
        #             else:
        #                 print(f"B win at {j+1} round")
        if A_score>B_score:
            A_win+=1
        elif A_score<B_score:
            B_win+=1
            if A_score==2:
                A_two_win_B_finally_win+=1
            if A_score==0:
                A_zero_win_B_finally_win+=1
print(A_win,B_win,A_two_win_B_finally_win,A_zero_win_B_finally_win)
print(possibilities)
```

The above code will output with the correct answer "420" for part a).